# Why does the page scroll up when I submit a form?

Tags: php, html, scroll

I have made the following form. When I select any of the options, the
page automatically scrolls up. Any ideas how do I fix it?

Here is HTML code:

```
 <form method="get" action="">
    <select id="training_session" name="lang" onchange=this.form.submit()>
    <option value=""<?php if($_GET['lang'] === '') echo 'selected' ?>>[All languages]</option>
    <option value="English" <?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'English') echo 'selected' ?>>English</option>
    <option value="Portuguese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Portuguese') echo 'selected' ?>>Portuguese</option>
    <option value="French"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'French') echo 'selected' ?>>French</option>
    <option value="Italian"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Italian') echo 'selected' ?>>Italian</option>
    <option value="Japanese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Japanese') echo 'selected' ?>>Japanese</option>
    </form>
    <noscript><input type="hidden" value="filter"></noscript>
```

Comment: page it's reloading. So or (1) add an ajax call and update (2) add an internal link to new language page and call my_translated_page.php#link_at_right_height

Answer (score 2):

The page isn't scrolling up.

```
onchange=this.form.submit()
```

The form is submitting, and the page is reloading.

The new version of the page loads from the top.

Comment: so there is no fixing that?

Comment: i just dont like how it loads again

Comment: There isn't really a sane way to change the language of all the content on the page without loading the whole page again.

Answer (score 1):

As you are submitting the page, it reloads at the top.

Here is a workaround :

First get the scroll position before submitting and submit it with the form :

```
 <form method="get" action="">
    <select id="training_session" name="lang" onchange="document.getElementById('sc_top').value=document.body.scrollTop;this.form.submit()">
    <option value=""<?php if($_GET['lang'] === '') echo 'selected' ?>>[All languages]</option>
    <option value="English" <?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'English') echo 'selected' ?>>English</option>
    <option value="Portuguese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Portuguese') echo 'selected' ?>>Portuguese</option>
    <option value="French"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'French') echo 'selected' ?>>French</option>
    <option value="Italian"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Italian') echo 'selected' ?>>Italian</option>
    <option value="Japanese"<?php if($_GET['lang'] === 'Japanese') echo 'selected' ?>>Japanese</option>
    </select>
    <input type='hidden' name='scrollTop' id='sc_top'/>
    </form>
    <noscript><input type="hidden" value="filter"></noscript>
```

Then edit your `body` tag to set this position again when page is loaded :

```
<body onload="document.body.scrollTop = <?=intval($_GET['scrollTop']);?>">
```

Comment: @Quentin That's wrong, I'm using htmlentities on the value.

Comment: That only stops people from creating an element or attribute that takes JavaScript as its value. `onload` already takes JavaScript as its value so `htmlentities` doesn't protect you against XSS there.

Comment: OK, `intval` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an id tag inside the action parameter. If you use php to manipulate the inputs, your php has to be inside that same particular file.

```html
<form method="get" action="#training_session">
    <select id="training_session" name="lang" 
</form>
```

So set the action to an id you want the user to jump after submitting the form.